# Inverse of $f(x)=x^3$ function

Tags: functions

please help me :can we inverse this function: $f(x)=x^3$? I know that if a function is a bijective function only then it can be inversed. Is this a bijective function?

Comment: What is the definition of Bijective?  How do you go about proving whether a function has this property?

Comment: Bijective function is a function which is both onto function and one-one function

Comment: How do you prove that a function is one to one?  How do you prove that it is onto?  Do those hold for this function?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, indeed, it is both [one-to-one (injective) and onto (surjective), and hence it is bijective.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection,_injection_and_surjection)

To show it is one-to-one, show that $f(x_1) = f(x_2) \implies x_1 = x_2$.

To show that it is onto, note that the image of $f$ is the entire codomain: the set of all real numbers. So for every $y \in \mathbb R$, there exists an $x\in \mathbb R$ such that $f(x) = y$.

So its inverse exists.

---

To find the inverse $f^{-1}$:

- Solve for $x$ as a function of $y$: $$x = \sqrt[\large 3] y$$
- swap $x$ for $y$: $$f^{-1}(x) = \sqrt[\large 3] x$$

Comment: Actually, isn't it every element $y$ in the *codomain* which must satisy $f(x)=y$ for some $x$ in the domain for a function to be onto? In this case of course the domain is the same as the codomain.

Comment: Yes, @bluesh34, I simply used "image" to name "codomain".

Comment: Seems to me you should say 'the image of $f$ is the entire codomain'.

Comment: I've got to get my grammar going, @bluesh34! ;-)

Comment: ...would I be too fussy if I were to ask for $f^{-1}(x)=\text{sgn}(x)\sqrt[3]{|x|}$??

Comment: It is interesting that $\sqrt[3]{x}$ is *defined* as the function that is a (right) inverse of $f$, so saying that $f^{-1}(x) = \sqrt[3]{x}$ doesn't say much. It certainly doesn't prove that the inverse exists, and it doesn't prove surjectivity. I think it would be more correct to prove surjectivity using the mean value theorem, without appealing to cubic roots.

Comment: Although maybe you don't mean to appeal to cubic roots. Sorry, I'm not criticizing, I'm only expressing a worry just in case :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Check whether your function $f:X\to Y$  satisfies

$1.f(x_1)=f(x_2)\Rightarrow x_1=x_2$

$2. \forall x\in Y\exists y\in X \ni f(y)=x$

$1\Rightarrow$ $f$ is injective and $2\Rightarrow f$ is surjective, A function is bijective if it is injective and surjective.

Comment: Hint: write $f(x) \to x,~~ x \to y$ then solve $x=y^3$.